# Query optimization for laravel pagination

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using laravel pagination .I am new to laravel and I having following query to get records from the job table which is bind to the site table with  300k records in job table and 10k records in site.I also set the indexing for faster result.when the data fetched with LIMIT 0,10  it takes 0.000 secs but with LIMIT 299990,0 it takes too much time. To solve this problem I changed the Query from Query1 to Query2.

Query1:

```
SELECT 
    s.site_name, s.postcode, j.contarct_code, j.job_num, s.site_id 
FROM 
    to_jobs as j 
LEFT JOIN  
    to_sites as s ON j.fk_site_id = s.site_id  
LIMIT  
    299970, 10
```

Query2:

```
SELECT 
    s.site_name, s.postcode, j.contarct_code, j.job_num, s.site_id 
FROM 
    to_jobs as j 
LEFT JOIN  
    to_sites as s  ON j.fk_site_id = s.site_id  
WHERE
    j.rec_id > 299970  
LIMIT  
    10
```

I got my expected result but when I place the query to the laravel pagination it gives wrong total of record.

Query 1 with laravel code:

```
->select('s.site_name','s.postcode','j.contarct_code','j.job_num','j.rec_id','s.site_id')
->leftJoin('to_sites as s', 'j.fk_site_id', '=', 's.site_id')
->paginate(10);
```

total = 299 997

Query 2 with laravel code:

```
->select('s.site_name','s.postcode','j.contarct_code','j.job_num','j.rec_id','s.site_id')
->leftJoin('to_sites as s', 'j.fk_site_id', '=', 's.site_id')
->where('j.rec_id', '>', '1067512')
->paginate(10);
```

total = 49

Data fetching time issue solved but pagination records changed. Any other solution for this?

Comment: When you add `where('j.rec_id', '>', '1067512')` this mean count query get few data ,coz yiy skip this data which `id < 1067512`  its very common , that your pagination will change

Comment: yes i know the reason but what the other way ?