# convert the sub query to the laravel sub query

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following query want to convert to the laravel subquery .

```
    SELECT to_jobs.rec_id,to_jobs.contarct_code, to_jobs.job_num , to_sites.site_name, to_sites.postcode, to_sites.site_id 
      FROM to_jobs
 LEFT JOIN to_sites   
        ON to_jobs.fk_site_id = to_sites.site_id
      JOIN (SELECT rec_id
              FROM to_jobs 
             LIMIT 299990, 10) AS t ON t.rec_id = to_jobs.rec_id
```

Answer (score 3):

equivalent of

```
    SELECT to_jobs.rec_id,to_jobs.contarct_code, to_jobs.job_num , to_sites.site_name, to_sites.postcode, to_sites.site_id 
      FROM to_jobs
```

to laravel is

```
DB::table('to_jobs')
    ->select(array(
      'to_jobs.rec_id',
      'to_jobs.contarct_code',
      'to_jobs.job_num',
      'to_sites.site_name',
      'to_sites.postcode',
      'to_sites.site_id' 
     ))
```

equivalent of

```
   LEFT JOIN to_sites   
          ON to_jobs.fk_site_id = to_sites.site_id
```

into laravel is

```
->leftJoin('to_sites', 'to_jobs.fk_site_id', '=', 'to_sites.id')
```

while equivalent of

```
   JOIN (SELECT rec_id 
           FROM to_jobs 
          LIMIT 299990, 10) AS t 
             ON t.rec_id = to_jobs.rec_id
```

into laravel is

```
->join(DB::raw('(SELECT rec_id FROM   to_jobs LIMIT  299990, 10) AS t'), function($join) {
            $join->on('t.rec_id ', '=', 'to_jobs.rec_id');
        })
```

so your query builder would be like this

```
DB::table('to_jobs')
    ->select(array(
        'to_jobs.rec_id',
        'to_jobs.contarct_code',
        'to_jobs.job_num',
        'to_sites.site_name',
        'to_sites.postcode',
        'to_sites.site_id' 
        ))
    ->leftJoin('to_sites', 'to_jobs.fk_site_id', '=', 'to_sites.id')
    ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT rec_id FROM   to_jobs LIMIT  299990, 10) AS t'), function($join) {
            $join->on('t.rec_id ', '=', 'to_jobs.rec_id');
        })
```

Comment: how to add ->paginate(10); to this query. I try to add by adding ->paginate(10); at the last but not working. returning an error  "Unknown column 't.rec_id ' in 'on clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `to_jobs` left join `to_sites` on `to_jobs`.`fk_site_id` = `to_sites`.`site_id` inner join (SELECT rec_id FROM to_jobs LIMIT 299990, 10) AS t on `t`.`rec_id ` = `to_jobs`.`rec_id`)"

Comment: @Alfizamalek but without paginate() the query builder doesn't produce an error?

Comment: no I want to add paginate(). so i am asking how i can add to this query?

Comment: can you show your query builder maybe screen shot would do

Comment: actually i m trying to solve the issue of query timing ,pagination with lots of records so my actual issue is on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545523/query-optimization-for-laravel-pagination please help if you can.thanks in advance.

Comment: @Alfizamalek it error because of `rec_id ` which should not have space after it just remove the space by changing `$join->on('t.rec_id ', '=', 'to_jobs.rec_id');` to `$join->on('t.rec_id', '=', 'to_jobs.rec_id');` don't forget to mark it answer if this problem is now totally fix

Comment: can you please help for the given link query.how to optimize the query with limit and pagination together. please help if you know.

Comment: Your query execute slow?

Comment: query get slow on last records only like if i am fetching data on page 3,4,5 or any from 100 its works fast but when i go to page 30000 it taking time more as compare to the top pages. please comment or ans on the given link question.

Comment: Of course its because you are using sub query

Comment: no theres no one subquery at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545523/query-optimization-for-laravel-pagination    the original quesry is at this url and it uses join only and pagination please come to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545523/query-optimization-for-laravel-pagination and comment there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be like this, when you need subquery you should use function..
I am showing you an example..

```
Products::whereIn('id', function($query){
    $query->select('paper_type_id')
    ->from(with(new ProductCategory)->getTable())
    ->whereIn('category_id', ['223', '15'])
    ->where('active', 1);
})->get();
```

Reference::
[Laravel 5.0 subquery example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres)